# Can't pass params to external php file

Tags: joomla-3.x, module-params, contact-form

I'm trying to make a simple contact form but I can't pass params from my module to external `action="contact.php"` file.

---

This is how I'm trying to get parameters to an external file:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$app->initialise();

$session = JFactory::getSession();

jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );

$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery("SELECT params FROM #__modules WHERE module = 'mod_my_contact_form'");

$module = $db->loadObject();
$params = new JRegistry($module->params);

$contact_email = $params->get('myemail');
```

Result of the `print_r('My e-mail: ' . $contact_email);` stays empty:

> My e-mail:

---

What might be the cause of this issue?

---

**EDIT:**
I've tried that method but without any results:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$app->initialise();

jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_my_contact_form');

$registry = new JRegistry();
$params = $registry->loadString($module->params);

$contact_email = $params->get('myemail');
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

File structure:

```
mod_my_contact_form/
    tmpl/
       includes/
            contact.php
       default.php
     helper.php
     mod_my_contact_form.php
     mod_my_contact_form.xml
```

---

**EDIT 3:**
I think the xml is built properly. This is how looks the param part:

```
...
    ...
    <fieldset name="contact_form" label="Contact Form">
        <field name="myemail" type="email" label="JGLOBAL_EMAIL" description="E-mail where you will receive all messages" size="30" class="inputbox" validate="email" />
    </fieldset>
   </fields>
  </config>
</extension>
```

Comment: Where is your file contact.php file ?? Can you show the file structure ?

Comment: Your second code snippet should work seems you have something wrong in your xml file(manifest xml)

Answer (score 2):

By looking at updated xml file, I see only one issue that you haven't used 
`<fields name="params"></fields>` in config tag and hence your modparams object showing blank. Try below xml snippet for configs and check one more time the `$module->params` values.

```
<config>
<fields name="params">
<fieldset name="contact_form" label="Contact Form">
<field name="myemail" type="email" label="JGLOBAL_EMAIL" description="E-mail where you will receive all messages" size="30" class="inputbox" validate="email" />
</fieldset>
</fields>
</config>
```

Hope this will solve your problem :)

**EDIT :**
By Looking at your comment I tried my self to develop module.Below are the steps -

1. I followed file structure given in question.
2. Here is My xml(`mod_my_contact_form.xml`)

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <extension version="3.0" type="module" client ="site" method="upgrade">
          <name>mod_my_contact_form</name>
       <files>
        <filename module="mod_my_contact_form">mod_my_contact_form.php</filename>
          <filename>index.html</filename>
          <folder>tmpl</folder>
       </files>
   <config>
       <fields name="params">
           <fieldset name="contact_form" label="Contact Form">
               <field name="myemail" type="email" label="JGLOBAL_EMAIL" description="E-mail where you will receive all messages" size="30" class="inputbox" validate="email" />
           </fieldset>
      </fields>
   </config>
   </extension>`
3. Here is Main PHP file of module(`mod_my_contact_form.php`)

   `<?php
   // No direct access.
   defined('_JEXEC') or die();
   echo "I am from Main File";
   //Load default.php
   require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_my_contact_form');
   ?>`
4. Here is My `default.php`

   `<?php
   echo "<br>I am from Default file";
   //Here I have loaded contact.php to send call there.
   require_once 'modules/mod_my_contact_form/tmpl/includes/contact.php';
   ?>`
5. I didn't do any different thing in `contact.php`, Just put down your code snippet.

   `<?php
    echo "<br>I am from contact php";
    $app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
    $app->initialise();
    jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
    $module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_my_contact_form');
    $registry = new JRegistry();
    $params = $registry->loadString($module->params);
    $contact_email = $params->get('myemail');
    echo "<br>Here is my params Email=> ".$contact_email;
   ?>`

**NOTE : I have just written code which need to go call into contact.php as we wanted to get params into contact.php file. Hence those required and all other stuff is used. So please use your code accordingly in respective files.**

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work. The fields tag has been there already in the past. Thanks for the help anyway @Sudhir.

Comment: Is Solution not working ?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not.

Comment: Ok, Let me check once again, I will be doing same module as you have. Let me try :)

Comment: @Frostbourn - Updated Answer with detailed code, This is working correctly at my end and shows email in contact.php file. Let me know if still you face any specific issue.

Comment: Everythings seems to be correct but it didn't work.. I checked on two different websites. I think this might be an issue somewhere else.